# Append text at the end of a specific line

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

I have a file with multiple lines. What I am trying to accomplish is add a string at the end of a commando.

I have a script that installs a tool automatically. Now some things have changes in the sources.
I need to add `contrib non-free` at the end of this line:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
```

It should look at this:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Linux, you'll have the GNU version of sed (which has an `-i` option for 'in-place' editing of files):

```
sed -i '/deb http:\/\/ftp.us.debian.org\/debian\/wheezy main/s/$/ contrib non-free/' file.sh
```

In the sed command, the stuff between the first two `//` tells sed to search for a line containing that -- so `sed '/foo/'` would search for lines containing 'foo'. Because your line contains forward-slashes, those need to be escaped. the `s/$/ contrib non-free` tells sed to replace the end of the line (represented by the dollar sign) with ' contrib non-free'. The general form is `s/replace this/with this/`. Taken together, this searches for the lines you want and then tacks your text onto the end.

If you just want to alter the end of *every* line in the file:

```
sed -i 's/$/ contrib non-free/'
```

Using the standard text editor, ed, is very *slightly* more portable, but in general you'll find yourself using sed for these tasks more often (or, preferably, a decent text editor such as vim).

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/deb http:\/\/ftp.us.debian.org\/debian\/wheezy main/s/$/ contrib non-free/' w q | ed file.sh
```